# how configure jdk 7 from remote sources as execution/compile toolchain in bazel?

Tags: bazel

I am trying to use a old version of jdk (7) in bazel for run a java_binary output as tool in the compilation process.
From the example code and following the documentation of bazel [config java toolchains](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
I created a WORKSPACE where get the remotejdk:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:remote_java_repository.bzl", "remote_java_repository")

remote_java_repository(
    name = "remotejdk",
    prefix = "remotejdk", # Can be used with --java_runtime_version=openjdk_canary_11
    version = "7",            # or --java_runtime_version=11
    exec_compatible_with = [   # Specifies constraints this JVM is compatible with "@platforms//cpu:arm",
        "@platforms//os:linux",
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64"
    ],
    urls=["https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7u75/ri/openjdk-7u75-b13-linux-x64-18_dec_2014.tar.gz"],
    sha256 = "56d84d0bfc8c1194d501c889765a387e949d6a063feef6608e5e12b8152411fb")
```

and a BUILD file that define the toolchain

```
load("@rules_java//java:defs.bzl", "java_binary", "java_library")
load("//:create_file.bzl", "call_java_binary")

load(
    "@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:default_java_toolchain.bzl",
    "default_java_toolchain", "VANILLA_TOOLCHAIN_CONFIGURATION"
)

default_java_toolchain(
    name = "repository_default_toolchain",
    configuration = VANILLA_TOOLCHAIN_CONFIGURATION,        # One of predefined configurations
    java_runtime = "@remotejdk//:jdk", # JDK to use for compilation and toolchain's tools execution
    jvm_opts = [],
    source_version = "7",
)

call_java_binary(
    name = "CreateFile",
)

java_binary(
    name = "ProjectRunner",
    srcs = ["src/main/java/com/example/ProjectRunner.java"],
    main_class = "com.example.ProjectRunner",
    deps = [":greeter"],
)

java_library(
    name = "greeter",
    srcs = ["src/main/java/com/example/Greeting.java"],
    visibility = ["//src/main/java/com/example/cmdline:__pkg__"],
)
```

when I try set specifically //:repository_default_toolchain and the language version as descrived in the documentation:
`bazel build //:CreateFile --extra_toolchains=//:repository_default_toolchain_definition --java_language_version=7 --java_runtime_version=7`

the toolchain is descarted with the error:

```
Type @bazel_tools//tools/jdk:runtime_toolchain_type: target platform @local_config_platform//:host: Rejected toolchain @remotejdk//:jdk; mismatching config settings: prefix_version_setting
```

and fallback to openjdk11_linux again.
With `bazel query --output=build "@remotejdk_toolchain_config_repo//:toolchain" 2>/dev/null` i looked for the value of prefix_version_setting and it is remotejdk_7
which is the proper way to setup jdk 7 as toolchain?

- the code is the java example from bazel/examples

Best regards

Comment: A temporary workaround is to install jdk in our build environment and set JAVA_HOME to /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk. Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: `INFO: ToolchainResolution:     Type @bazel_tools//tools/jdk:runtime_toolchain_type: target platform @local_config_platform//:host: Rejected toolchain @local_jdk//:jdk; mismatching config settings: local_jdk_name_version
_setting `
The error is diferent but i think is the same meaning